# After compiling with PackageCompiler, Julia fails to start

Tags: windows, julia

I have compiled some images with `PackageCompiler.create_sys_img` on Julia 1.6. Now when I click on the Julia icon on windows it fails to start. I can't see any error messages since the window closed so fast.

How do I rememdy this? Where do I find the old sys image and manually replace it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the sys.dll in the Julia folder. Something like

```
C:\Users\USERID\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.6.0-beta1\lib\julia
```

and replace the `sys.dll` file with `sys.dll.backup`.

Restart Julia.